# Save exception Logs in file

Tags: java, exception, logging

I am designing java desktop application and want give it to another person for using in .jar file.
I want to save exception logs in a text file for future maintenance.
What is the best way?!

Comment: What logging framework are you using?  Have you tried a Google search for examples or tutorials?  As it stands, your question is far too broad/generic for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Yes I tried! I get some information about apache log4j logging but I want a simple and best way!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the logging framework like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) or [Java logging API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html). Then you should configure file appender to write log messages in file. Almost all logging API's have possibility to log exceptions. For example log4j [Logger](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html) interface has method [debug](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#debug%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) with 2 parameters. First parameter is error message and the second one is the exception to log, including its stack trace.

Here is example of using Logger interface:

```
package com.azry.test;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class TestLogging {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestLogging.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Here is sample logging of exception object (including stacktrace)
        log.error("Some error occurred", new NullPointerException());
    }
}
```

Note that you should have `log4j.properties` configuration file in you classpath. Below is the sample configuration file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\loging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Yes I know, Can you please help me how to store logs in a text file with some codes?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what's the best way, I'm using [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) library